# How to associate/ connect the client to zookeeper server?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have learn basic zookeeper concept and did a sample project, But I only it only local pc or one computer.

I understand the zookeeper but still confused on how the client connect to the zookeeper server if they are not in one computer? for instance, if we start a zookeeper server in my own computer, and we can use connect() like connect 2181 to connect to the zookeeper server, that make sense, since they are all in one computer have have some association in lower layer. But what if the zookeeper server and client they are separated into two computer? how can we handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what language you're using for the client, so this will have to be a generic answer.

The client and server communicate over TCP. This requires that the client simply know the server's host and port. In general, your ZooKeeper servers bind to some private network interface. For instance, your *zoo.conf* configuration file might contain a line like the following:

```
clientPort=2181
server.1=123.456.789.1:2888:3888
```

The first portion of the *server.1* section *123.456.789.1* is the host to which the ZooKeeper server will bind. As long as this host is not the loop back interface (i.e. *localhost* or *127.0.0.1*) you should be able to connect to that host from another machine on the client port *2181*. So, for instance, in Java I create a new ZkClient that points to that host and port:

```
ZkClient client = new ZkClient("123.456.789.1:2181");
```

Comment: Thx for answering. And it make more sense. It likes we deployed zookeeper server on computer A, and run it(configure as well ). And then we start another computer B and use Java to create a client side program, connect it to A with port and host? Is that correct? And what about the relation between node client? The zookeeper can monitor/watch the state of node, like the node died the watch will trigger. Do we create the node in computer B or A or both? How do they interact? Thx so much!!

Comment: It seems always the client gets disconnected, from java api, how to keep it alive, so that I can receive the distributed watcher service..!

Comment: How can I start zookeeper on top of private network ? Instead of making it public, can I run it on top of private network ?